# jQuery: get animate to repeat only after full completion

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, sequence

**EDIT:** *thanks to mplungian, I now know about debounce and particularly about throttle which seems a very good solution to my problem. But I don't know how to implement this with jQuery "animate" yet.*

I have this script:

```
$(document).on('click','#right',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('ready')){
        $(this).removeClass('ready');
        $('#slider').animate(
            {'margin-left': '-=200px'},
            { duration:1100,easing:'easeOutElastic',queue: false,complete:function()
                {
                    $('#right').addClass('ready');
                }
            }
        )
        // ...
        sliderPosition++;   
    }

})
```

So, this is a slider triggered on a button click.
As there is a vital animation that has to be completed before the user clicks again (otherwise the slider width is quickly messed up), I used a "ready" class that prevents the user from clicking until the previous animation is finished.

Tehnically, it works well but it doesn't "feel" right, the slider doesn't look like "responsive" enough, as fast clickers will only get to see the slider move every other of their clicks.

But if I get rid of the ".ready" condition, then the slider is quickly messed up because each animation can be fired before the previous one is finished.

**So, is there a way for the script to take each and every click into account but just differ them until all the previous iterations of the same animation are finished?**

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need a [debounce](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+debounce+site:stackoverflow.com) - perhaps [debounce jquery click animation](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+debounce+click+animation+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I'm reading about it, thanks. I didn't know this existed and, in fact, Throttle might be better than Debounce in my case. But the syntax an the way I should implemented for an animation is still obscure. The use cases shown don't imply jQuery "animate". So, I'm on it but I'm not sure yet how it would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.stop`

```
$('#slider').stop().animate(
```

like this

```
$(document).on('click','#right',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('ready')){
        $(this).removeClass('ready');
        $('#slider').stop().animate(
            {'margin-left': '-=200px'},
            { duration:1100,easing:'easeOutElastic',queue: false,complete:function()
                {
                    $('#right').addClass('ready');
                }
            }
        )
        // ...
        sliderPosition++;   
    }
})
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Stop() will prevent the animation from completing when te next click arrives, which is the opposite of what I asked for (I need the animation to complete each time otherwise, my sliding is interrupted and pictures are offset on screen)

Comment: What I did is in the code and described in the question: I added a "ready" condition so that the animation isn't interrupted. That's what I did. And it works. But Then each click won't fire an animation animation. Which is a problem. What I want is each click to be accounted for but let each animation to be able to complete before firing the next one. For instance, if I click 10 times in 5 seconds to fire a 2 seconds animation, each 2s animation will complete and the whole animation sequence will take 20 seconds. My question might be long but it's all in there.

Answer (score 0):

It's been solved using throttle:

```
let timeout;

const throttle = (func, limit) => {
    if (!timeout) {
        func();
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          timeout = undefined;
        }, limit);
    }
};

$(document).on('click','#right',function(){
    throttle(function(){
        $('#slider').animate(
            {'margin-left': '-=200px'},
            { duration:1100,easing:'easeOutElastic',queue: false}
        )
        // ...
        sliderPosition++; 
    }, 500);
})
```

It's the best of both worlds as the animations are served in a steady pace during the clicking no matter how many clicks. So this will give the impression that the slider is totally reactive while not necessarily firing an animation on each and every click if they are too quick and to numerous.
So it's not so much about the amount of clicks than about keeping the animation going WHILE you are clicking.